# Get Day Name from Google Calendar API

Tags: php, wordpress, google-calendar-api

I am hoping this is easy to answer. I am working with the Google Calendar API within WordPress and I have returned all of the information I need except the Day Name (E.G. Monday, Tuesday, etc). Is there an easy way to get this data? Here is the loop I am using (I have omitted the actual Call since it contains sensitive info):

```
if( is_page(16) ) {
    foreach($events as $event) {
      $datetime_start = date('F j, Y', strtotime($event->start->dateTime));
      $datetime_time_start = date('g:i', strtotime($event->start->dateTime));
      $datetime_end = date('F j, Y\ g:i', strtotime($event->end->dateTime));

      echo
      '<p>' .
          '<strong>Date Start:  </strong>' . $datetime_start .
      '<br>' .
      '<strong>Date End:  </strong>' . $datetime_end .
          '<br>' .
      '<strong>Location: </strong>' . $event->location .
      '<br>' .
      '<strong>Time Only:   </strong>' . $datetime_time_start .
      '<br>' .
      '<strong>Description: </strong>' . $event->description .
      '<br>' .
      '<strong>Title: </strong>' . $event->getSummary() .
      '<strong>Day:  </strong>' . $event->day .
      '<p>';
    }
}
```

I have tried `$event->day` and got nothing as I expected. I also tried `getDay()` and also returned nothing as expected (sometimes you get lucky). All of the above code works, I just can't figure out how to get the Day Name. I have been using Google's Calendar API Docs to get all of what I have above. Link here:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations

However, I was unable to locate any resources that give the Day Name. If it is not possible is there a workaround or another solution perhaps? We cannot use a plugin since we are customizing the look and layout of the Events for a College Events Page and we need to have the raw data.

Note: The code is only a quick and dirty dump to make sure I have the data I need before actually integrating it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the php documentation for `date()` it states that “l” (lower case L) is used for a textual version of the day.

See here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Ah :facepalm: I can't believe I missed that. Thank You very much! Can someone please upvote this answer*. I do not have enough reputation to do so. Thank you again!